# Formatting Data in R

Tags: r, csv, import, file-io

Suppose I'm importing a csv file in R to create R dataset. Now this file has numeric, character,data & percentage value. How to make sure that data I'm importing will have the same data format as in Raw file.

In SAS, we generally have this option of formatting the data while importing. Here's the example

```
data test ;  
           infile "c:\mydocument\raw.csv" 
           delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767
           firstobs=2 ;

           input 
              varA         
              varB         : $50.
              varC        : date9.
              varD      : Percent5.2
              varE      : $20.
;
run;
```

Is there any option in R that can do the same kind of action? If somebody can give me some reference on it, it will be great!

Example based on answer below:

```
Local<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Raw.csv",colClasses = c("character","character","Date","character","character","character","character","character","character","character","numeric","numeric", "numeric","numeric"),row.names=1)
```

I used the following code based on **Dason's** example. But I'm getting the following error. Will it be possible for you to tell me why this error is coming? You have been very helpful.

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '.'
```

Thank you. Rgds.

Comment: Maybe a `.` is used for NA...However, this is hard to tell for us as your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your comment. I have "." in my data. So that error has been taken care of. But another error is coming. "Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". I guess I've to take care of it myself.

Comment: Or if you don't succeed, ask another question, preferably including a reproducible example. I also added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colClasses parameter of read.csv is what you want.  From `?read.csv`:

```
colClasses: character.  A vector of classes to be assumed for the
          columns.  Recycled as necessary, or if the character vector
          is named, unspecified values are taken to be ‘NA’.

          Possible values are ‘NA’ (the default, when ‘type.convert’ is
          used), ‘"NULL"’ (when the column is skipped), one of the
          atomic vector classes (logical, integer, numeric, complex,
          character, raw), or ‘"factor"’, ‘"Date"’ or ‘"POSIXct"’.
          Otherwise there needs to be an ‘as’ method (from package
          ‘methods’) for conversion from ‘"character"’ to the specified
          formal class.

          Note that ‘colClasses’ is specified per column (not per
          variable) and so includes the column of row names (if any).
```

Some example use

```
dat <- data.frame(num = 1:4, ch = letters[1:4])
write.csv(dat, file = "test.csv")
read.csv("test.csv", 
          colClasses = c(NA, "numeric", "character"),
          row.names = 1)
#  num ch
#1   1  a
#2   2  b
#3   3  c
#4   4  d
out <- read.csv("test.csv", 
                 colClasses = c(NA, "numeric", "character"),
                 row.names = 1)
str(out)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ num: num  1 2 3 4
# $ ch : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Answer (score 1):

In regard to your second error message, what is probably happening is that `.` is used as a special character, probably meant to show where there where NA's in the dataset. You can use the `na.strings` argument to tell `read.csv` which strings are considered NA.